# Azure AD B2C built in policy upload

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How do I programmatically upload a built in policy in azure active directory b2c blade?

Does anyone know why the upload policy button is disabled in azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

The **Upload Policy** button is available for custom policies only.